# Redirect only homepage (root) based on browser language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make only my homepage (root) redirect by browser language. What I got now (see below) redirects no matter what URL you type in. Can I set som conditional state or anything to just make this rule work on my homepage (subdomain.mydomain.com)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (da) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://subdomain.mydomain.com/dk/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (no) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://subdomain.mydomain.com/no/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `^/?$` regex to match landing page like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} da [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dk/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} no [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /no/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much, anubhava.